# XAML TextBlock TextAlignment vs HorizontalAlignment

Tags: xaml, alignment, textblock, text-alignment

Consider the following XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="Some Text" TextAlignment="Right" />
    <TextBlock Text="Some Text" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
</Grid>
```

So long as both `TextBlock`s are set to the same `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column`, they will always appear in the same place - one on top of the other.

Similar concept, here - with the 2 lines of text in both the `StackPanel`s aligning exactly:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Line One" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
        <TextBlock Text="Line Two" TextAlignment="Right" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Line One" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
        <TextBlock Text="Line Two" TextAlignment="Right" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And so on...

---

In terms of displaying the text to the right of the parent, the `TextAlignment` and `HorizontalAlignment` attributes are both doing the same thing - from what I can see.

Can anybody tell me what the actual difference between `TextAlignment` and `HorizontalAlignment` is, when it comes to `TextBlock`s?

Is there a preferred choice of the two to use?

Are there any implications to using either?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`HorizontalAlignment` determines the alignment of the `TextBox` relative to its parent.

`TextAlignment` determines the alignment of the text within the `TextBox`

Comment: Well dang, beat me while making an example, if you want another image for visual I was going to slap [this image](http://i.imgur.com/0risUbE.png) on mine to visualize like a "center"

Comment: Thank you both @EdPlunkett and ChrisW.! That's a superb explanation and some great example illustrations :) This had made it a lot clearer to see the differences. Cheers, guys!